# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() signs in the newly created user

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase/node app up and running, and I've, until now, just been testing it on my own.

However, I finally got to a point that I'd like others to test it out, so I deployed and provided a friend with the URL.

And immediately, when he created an account (which in my app is via `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`), when I visit the page it shows as being logged in as my friend.

When I hit the logout route and login with my credentials, he sees the page as being logged in as me.

All of my routes are using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {...})`

I can't for the life of me find any information on what I might have done wrong here. Any help or insight would be amazing. Also, I don't even know what info I should include in this question, so even guidance on that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a user through the [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#create-user-with-email-and-password) method, **on success this user will also be signed in to your application**, as explained in the doc.

When you hit the `logout` route (which I guess is calling the [`signOut()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sign-out) method), you are actually signing out this user. And when you sign in again with your own account, you see your user.

---

If you want to avoid this behaviour (being signed in as a new user you've just created), you will need to implement a different approach, for example call a Cloud Function that creates the new user.

You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents how to build, with a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), a module for allowing end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*.

Comment: Thank you @Renaud Tarnec. But I seem to not understand the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function. As it stands now, if any one user logs in, then any other person in the world who visits the site is signed in as that user. Is this how that method is meant to work? If so, how do you have a user sign in so that they are only signed in from their location?

Comment: Yes, anyone with your your Firebase config elements (e.g. `apiKey`), can create a new user in your Firebase project by calling the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method or by signing in a user for the first time using a federated identity provider, such as Google Sign-In or Facebook Login, or by calling the Auth REST API. It seems weird the first time you read that but this is the model of Firebase Authentication. The article I mentioned above explains how to protect your data. You will find a lot of articles on this point on the web.

Comment: Yes I took a look at your answer, thank you for the help, I eventually got there. The problem was I was using the client-side firebase.auth() on the server-side of my application. This is what was causing the strange behaviour. Thanks again for your  help!